# do ... while loop not breaking c++

Tags: c++, do-while, break

currently I'm having problems with this do ... while loop.

```
do { 
 // program code here
    cout << "Would you like to run the program again?(yes/no)";
    bool exit = false;
    string strexit;
    do {
        getline(cin, strexit);
        if (strexit == "no") {
            exit = false;
            break;
        }
        else if (strexit == "yes") {
            exit = true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Enter yes to rerun the program, and no to exit.\n";
        };
    } while (!exit);
    system("cls");
} while (exit);
return 0;
}
```

I researched online, how to break out of do ... while loops, and it's when the condition is true, it loops back again, but if its false it exits. 
So if you look at the code, if the user types in no, it sets exit = false, which takes it out of the bigger do while loop, where the break takes it out of the current do while loop.
If the user enters yes, it changes exit to true, which breaks it out of the current do ... while loop, but it doesn't break out of the second.

My question is, (or what I need help with) is that when the user inputs 'no', it cannot exit the do ... while loops, and I'm severely confused as to why. (It loops back to the beginning of the program.)

Comment: Why do you have two while loops here?

Comment: the first nested do while loop, is to make sure the user inputs the right answer (yes/no), so as you can see, it keeps on saying   cout << "Enter yes to rerun the program, and no to exit.\n"; until the user inputs yes or no. The second while loop, is for the user to have the option to rerun the whole program again. Is there some easier way for the user to rerun the whole program?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the (shortened) code

```
do
{
    bool exit = false;
    // ...
} while (!exit);
```

you actually have ***two different*** symbols named `exit`. Inside the loop you have the variable. Outside of the loop, and used for the condition, you have the function [`std::exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit). Which will be plain `exit` if you have `using namespace std;`.

The *function* `exit` when used in the condition will decay to a pointer to the function, and it will *never* be "false". So the condition `!exit` is always `true` and you have an infinite loop.

To solve this there are two things you need to do:

1. Learn that `using namespace std;` [is very bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
2. Move the variable `exit` to be defined outside the loop. And you should really rename to something more descriptive it as well (the word "exit" is a little bit to general).

Comment: I think a slightly better piece of advice here than avoiding `using namespace std;` would be "compile with warnings cranked up to max and treated as errors." On my machine, this produces a compiler error that immediately flags the issue, though I suspect on lower warning levels that this might not happen.

Comment: A third suggestion. Don't use `exit` as a variable. Use `exitLoop`, perhaps.

Comment: For what it's worth, `-Wall` on g++ exposes the mistake with a warning.

Comment: thanks for the help! I'm fairly new to c++, and have never heard that using namespace std; was bad. Thanks for the advice! although I do believe having to write std::cout everytime I want to output something in c++ is going to be quite extensive.

Comment: @templatetypedef How do you make your machine produce a compiler error that immediately flags the issue? I'm currently using Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: @AdamIsAProgrammer There's an easy solution to that: `using std::cout;`. That pulls in just `std::cout` into the current namespace, not everything from `std`. Or just get used to prefix everything from the standard library with `std::` (it doesn't really take that much time of effort :) )

Comment: Ah that makes sense, could you also use that for cin and string? such as using std::cout, std::cin, and std::string?. or you have to separate the lines?

Comment: @AdamIsAProgrammer You have to do it separately unfortunately.

Comment: "have never heard that using namespace std; was bad."  --   See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2785528

Answer (score 3):

I think @SomeProgrammerDude has given excellent advice that's well worth following--but I'd go a step further, and advise moving the code to get the user's response into a separate function so you can more easily reason about each part of the code in isolation:

```
bool check_for_exit() { 
    std::string prompt = "\nDo you want to exit the program? ";
    std::string strexit;

    do { 
        std::cout << prompt;
        std::getline(std::cin, strexit);
        prompt = "\nPlease enter yes or no";
    } while (strexit != "yes" && strexit != "no");
    return strexit == "yes";
}
```

Then you use that function in the code that does the real work, something on this order:

```
do {
    whatever();
} while (!check_for_exit());
```

It seems to me that this approach helps avoid many of the problems you encountered in your code.

Comment: Since, I'm still a new user to c++, I actually learnt about functions halfway through coding this project. So next time, I'd probably try to take it a step further and implement functions into my future projects. Thanks for the advice too though!